# Mounted Drive, Now it won't boot?

Tags: mount, windows

I was playing around with mounting and unmounting a Windows drive. I finished and tried to restart my computer, but Windows entered recovery mode and won't let me access my data. I know it's still there, since when I open GParted, it shows that 284Gb are being used, which is about how much all of my data is supposed to take up right now. When I mount it, however, it just gives me a couple of log files in a Windows folder. Any ideas?

Comment: If you comment out the line in `/etc/fstab` for the Windows/ntfs drive, does it boot? If it does, then uncomment the lne in `/etc/fstab` and use the command `mount -a` and see if it gives any errors.

Comment: Did you see any error in Windows boot? What are the entries in `/etc/fstab`? Did you write any file from Linux in that Windows drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late answer, but I figured out the solution. Turns out I accidentally mounted the drive and then forgot to unmount it, meaning my laptop couldn't find the drive anywhere. Just took the hard drive out, copied the files, and reinstalled Windows.